# Line graph ggplot - two lines, data points from same site/s

Tags: r, ggplot2

Sites on x axis are out of order and stacking over each other.
Have data formatted as:

```
line.dat
Site    Species Count
S1  Macropod    14.0
S1  Pig         0.6
S2  Macropod    22.1
S2  Pig         0.0
S3  Macropod    58.5
S3  Pig         1.3
S4  Macropod    11.9
S4  Pig         1.9
```

**code:**

```
ggplot(data=line.dat,aes(x=Site,y=Count, group=Species, colour=Species))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_point()
```

Just want one site 1-38 on the x-axis
Also, want in the order 1-38

[image]
[image]

Comment: they are probably factors. You will need to make a new, numeric column of only the numbers (using substring maybe) then use that as the x-axis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before running the ggplot, reorder your site factor level with

```
line.dat$Site <- factor(line.dat$Site, levels=paste0("S", 1:38))
```

This should reorder them to appear as S1, S2, S3... S38.

=====

In response to spacing out the x-axis label:

(i) generating random data:

```
test <- data.frame(Site = paste0("S", 1:38))
set.seed(4)
test$Count <- sample(1:80, 38, replace=TRUE)
test$Site <- factor(test$Site, levels=paste0("S", 1:38))
```

(ii) plotting with custom breaks and labels for `scale_x_continuous`

```
ggplot(test, aes(x=as.numeric(Site), y=Count)) + geom_line() + geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous("Site", breaks=seq(1,38,by=2), labels=paste0("S", seq(1,38,by=2)))
```

[image]

Comment: Worked  for original question.
Could you suggest an option to space them out, maybe only show every second site, "S", 1:19?

Comment: you can use `scale_x_discrete(breaks = <whatever values you want>)` to manually select which values to plot